# Нет кнопок управления окном в VS Code MacOS

Tags: visual-studio-code, macos

Нет кнопок управления окном в VS Code MacOS, так же не работает Cmd + Q.
Помогает только принудительное закрытие через местный диспетчер задач

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Может он запускается в полноэкранном режиме?

Comment: @Leonid нет, к тому же его ещё невозможно закрыть через cmd + Q